# What is the most efficient way to get rid off border-right of the first element of table header?

Tags: html, css

I have a table, I want to **get rid off** border-right of the first `td` of my `th`.

[image]

---

## HTML

```
<div class="container" <div class="row" style=" margin-right: 15px; margin-left: 15px;">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div id="piechart"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <table class="table table-bordered piechart-key ">
            <thead>
                <th colspan="2" ></th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Item Summary</th>
                <th>Item List</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td width="30"></td>
                    <td width="200">&gt; 50% of students answered these items correctly</td>
                    <td width="50">5/25</td>
                    <td width="100">5,10,15,19,23</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="30"></td>
                    <td width="200">50% up to 75% of students answered these items correctly</td>
                    <td width="50">8/25</td>
                    <td width="100">3,7,11,13,14,16,21,22</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="30"></td>
                    <td width="200">&ge; 75% of students answered these items correctly</td>
                    <td width="50">12/25</td>
                    <td width="100">1,2,4,6,8,9,12,17,18,20,24,25</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<hr style="height:5pt; visibility:hidden;" />
```

I've tried

```
.table th > td:first-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

No Effect, and the border is still there.

[Here is my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/w0b73dwt/11/)

What is the most efficient way to get rid off border-right of the first element of table header ?

Comment: you are talking about first td or th as you are showing in pic is th so little bit confused.

Comment: did u got my code??or i need to improve it??

Comment: can u put your related CSS  here

Comment: Click on the JSFiddle to see everything you need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The one you are highlighting is not the border it is two different column.
use this code to collapse them

```
     <td colspan="2"> </td>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this rule:

```
.table td, th {
  border: #c9cacb solid 1px !important;
}
```

This is overriding any modification you make to the border.

You'll need to do this:

```
.table th:first-child{
 border-right:none !important;   
}
.table th:nth-child(2){
 border-left:none !important;   
}
```

given that the second cell's border also affects the side border. Ideally though, get rid of the first important rule if you can.

Edit:

The rule you posted

```
.table th > td:first-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

also won't work, as you're referencing all table cells ('td') which are direct children of table-header cells ('th'), which won't occur in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS needs some improvement: try to correct it using `table`, not `.table`. You assigned class to the table (`class="table table-bordered piechart-key "`), which is seemingly not used and not required (you have just one table); class name is rather poorly worded, plus the statement per se contains another error - extra space at the end.

Hope this may help.

Answer (score -1):

just copy and paste

```
      <style>
       table, th, td {
     border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
        <div class="container" <div class="row" style=" margin-right: 15px; margin-left:   15px;">
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <div id="piechart"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-9">
      <table class="table table-bordered piechart-key ">
        <thead>
            <th colspan="2" ></th>

            <th>Item Summary</th>
            <th>Item List</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td width="30"></td>
                <td width="200">&gt; 50% of students answered these items   correctly</td>
                <td width="50">5/25</td>
                <td width="100">5,10,15,19,23</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="30"></td>
                <td width="200">50% up to 75% of students answered these   items correctly</td>
                <td width="50">8/25</td>
                <td width="100">3,7,11,13,14,16,21,22</td>
              </tr>
             <tr>
                <td width="30"></td>
                <td width="200">&ge; 75% of students answered these items  correctly</td>
                <td width="50">12/25</td>
                <td width="100">1,2,4,6,8,9,12,17,18,20,24,25</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <hr style="height:5pt; visibility:hidden;" />
```